# Messed up view in CandyBox 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I started playing Candybox 2 and I was really getting into it, it was hard to make things out but I went along with it, then I saw these pictures where the lines where perfectly matched and easy to see detail and I think my view is messed up some how...

What others seem to see:
[image]

What I see:
[image]

I really wanna play this game, but it is far too hard to see anything...